# Looping through rows of pandas when the equation also changes

Tags: python, pandas

- I need to ignore timestamps and loop through rows this way.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

time = ['11:50', '12:50', '13:50']
data_1 = {'time': time,
          'n1': [1, 5, 8],
          'n2': [2, 6 ,7],
          'n3': [3, 7 ,6],
          'n4': [4, 8, 5],
        }

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = data_1)
df1
```

I am trying to multiply:

- row 1 * (10^0)
- row 2 * (10^1)
- row 3 * (10^2)
- ...
- row n * (10^(n-1))

Before:

|  | time | n1 | n2 | n3 | n4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 11:50 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 12:50 | `5` | `6` | `7` | `8` |
| 2 | 13:50 | 8 | 7 | 6 | 5 |

Expected result:

|  | time | n1 | n2 | n3 | n4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 11:50 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 12:50 | 50 | 60 | 70 | 80 |
| 2 | 13:50 | 800 | 700 | 600 | 500 |

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `mul` on index axis:

```
df1.iloc[:, 1:] = df1.iloc[:, 1:].mul(10**df1.index, axis=0)
print(df1)

# Output
    time   n1   n2   n3   n4
0  11:50    1    2    3    4
1  12:50   50   60   70   80
2  13:50  800  700  600  500
```

You can replace `df1.index` by `np.arange(len(df1))` if your index is not a `RangeIndex`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this also numpy broadcasting and `get_indexer`,

```
df1.iloc[:, 1:] *= 10**df1.index.get_indexer(df1.index)[:, None]
df1
```

Output

```
    time   n1   n2   n3   n4
a  11:50    1    2    3    4
b  12:50   50   60   70   80
c  13:50  800  700  600  500
```

Works with none standard unique indexing:

Given df,

```
time = ['11:50', '12:50', '13:50']
data_1 = {'time': time,
          'n1': [1, 5, 8],
          'n2': [2, 6 ,7],
          'n3': [3, 7 ,6],
          'n4': [4, 8, 5],
        }

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = data_1, index=[*'abc'])
df1
```